# Invoking default model binder for query parameters from an AuthorizationHandler, given a HttpContext

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, authorization, asp.net-authorization

## Problem

In ASP.NET Core 2.2 I'm implementing an AuthorizationHandler (where I have access to the HttpContext of the incoming request).

How can I invoke the same model binder for query parameters that is used by MVC from within that AuthorizationHandler?

Ideally I would like to write an extension method which allows me to write something like:

```
HttpContext.Request.Query.BindValue<ICollection<MembershipType>>("membershipType");
```

Which returns a new instance of `ICollection<MembershipType>` based on the query parameter(s) named "membershipType" (and where `MembershipType` is an enum).

## Background

Let's assume I have a controller action where complex model binding for query parameters is performed, for example something like this (`MembershipType` is an enum):

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize("MyPolicyThatUsesMyRequirement")]
public Task<ActionResult<List<Member>>> GetMembers([FromQuery] ICollection<MembershipType> membershipTypeFilter = null)
{
    // skipping actual implementation
}
```

Now I want to create an AuthorizationHandler which only succeeds for certain combinations of `membershipTypeFilter` entries and user roles. This means that in my AuthorizationHandler I need to get access to the membershipTypeFilter parameter.

Let's look at the following skeleton of an AuthorizationHandler:

```
class MyRequirement : AuthorizationHandler<MyRequirement>, IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, MyRequirement requirement)
    {
        var mvcContext = context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext;

        // TODO: need access to query parameters here

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

`mvcContext.HttpContext.Request.Query` gives me access to the query parameters, but only in the form of a dictionary of string arrays. Of course I could parse that collection of strings and somehow turn it into a collection of enum values. But in this scenario it is crucial that this conversion is done in exactly the same manner as is done when MVC invokes my controller action. So I'm looking for a way to invoke the same model binder as MVC uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MVC Model Binding, it is implemented by [Bind](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/8d66f104f7f2ca42ee8b21f75b0e2b3e1abe2e00/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Controllers/ControllerBinderDelegateProvider.cs#L61). You will need to use it in your own code.

In my option, it is too overload for your requirement, the better option for you would be get value from query string directly.

```
var parameters = mvcContext
                        .ActionDescriptor
                        .Parameters
                        .Select(s => new
                        {
                            Name = s.Name,
                            Value = mvcContext.HttpContext.Request.Query[s.Name]
                        });
```

If you want to make a try with MVC Model Binding in `AuthorizationHandler`, try

```
public class MyNewRequirement : AuthorizationHandler<MyRequirement>, IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, MyRequirement requirement)
    {
        var mvcContext = context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext;
        //required service
        var _mvcOptions = mvcContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MvcOptions>>().Value;
        var parameterBinder = mvcContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ParameterBinder>();
        var _modelBinderFactory = mvcContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IModelBinderFactory>();
        var _modelMetadataProvider = mvcContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IModelMetadataProvider>();

        var controllerContext = new ControllerContext(mvcContext);
        controllerContext.ValueProviderFactories = new CopyOnWriteList<IValueProviderFactory>(_mvcOptions.ValueProviderFactories.ToArray());
        var valueProvider = await CompositeValueProvider.CreateAsync(controllerContext);
        var parameters = controllerContext.ActionDescriptor.Parameters;
        var parameterBindingInfo = GetParameterBindingInfo(
                        _modelBinderFactory,
                        _modelMetadataProvider,
                        controllerContext.ActionDescriptor,
                        _mvcOptions);

        for (var i = 0; i < parameters.Count; i++)
        {
            var parameter = parameters[i];
            var bindingInfo = parameterBindingInfo[i];
            var modelMetadata = bindingInfo.ModelMetadata;

            if (!modelMetadata.IsBindingAllowed)
            {
                continue;
            }

            var model = await parameterBinder.BindModelAsync(
                controllerContext,
                bindingInfo.ModelBinder,
                valueProvider,
                parameter,
                modelMetadata,
                value: null);
        }          

    }
    private static BinderItem[] GetParameterBindingInfo(
        IModelBinderFactory modelBinderFactory,
        IModelMetadataProvider modelMetadataProvider,
        ControllerActionDescriptor actionDescriptor,
        MvcOptions mvcOptions)
        {
            var parameters = actionDescriptor.Parameters;
            if (parameters.Count == 0)
            {
                return null;
            }

            var parameterBindingInfo = new BinderItem[parameters.Count];
            for (var i = 0; i < parameters.Count; i++)
            {
                var parameter = parameters[i];

                ModelMetadata metadata;
                if (mvcOptions.AllowValidatingTopLevelNodes &&
                    modelMetadataProvider is ModelMetadataProvider modelMetadataProviderBase &&
                    parameter is ControllerParameterDescriptor controllerParameterDescriptor)
                {
                    // The default model metadata provider derives from ModelMetadataProvider
                    // and can therefore supply information about attributes applied to parameters.
                    metadata = modelMetadataProviderBase.GetMetadataForParameter(controllerParameterDescriptor.ParameterInfo);
                }
                else
                {
                    // For backward compatibility, if there's a custom model metadata provider that
                    // only implements the older IModelMetadataProvider interface, access the more
                    // limited metadata information it supplies. In this scenario, validation attributes
                    // are not supported on parameters.
                    metadata = modelMetadataProvider.GetMetadataForType(parameter.ParameterType);
                }

                var binder = modelBinderFactory.CreateBinder(new ModelBinderFactoryContext
                {
                    BindingInfo = parameter.BindingInfo,
                    Metadata = metadata,
                    CacheToken = parameter,
                });

                parameterBindingInfo[i] = new BinderItem(binder, metadata);
            }

            return parameterBindingInfo;
        }
    private struct BinderItem
    {
        public BinderItem(IModelBinder modelBinder, ModelMetadata modelMetadata)
        {
            ModelBinder = modelBinder;
            ModelMetadata = modelMetadata;
        }

        public IModelBinder ModelBinder { get; }

        public ModelMetadata ModelMetadata { get; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Oh wow, this really seems to be a bit of an overkill... I think I will just do these checks in the action body (where I have access to everything I need) instead of writing custom policies and handlers.